# Making Tree with Nested Loops

Tags: java, tree

So, for my programming class, our teacher tasked us with making a tree out of *'s and other random characters. There has to be a star at the top of the tree that increases in size every so often, depending how large the user wants the tree. For some reason, if the number the user enters is greater than 15, the bottom half is too far to the right. I tried changing my code, but then everything less than 15 is too far the right. How can I get that to work?

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the tree you would like");
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    if ( a >= 12){
         d = 1;
    } else {
         d = 0;
    }
    //Top Half of Star
    for (int i = 0; i < a / 4; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < a; j++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
            b = b + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("");
        }
    //Bottom Half of Star
    for (int i = 1; i < a/4; i++){
        for (int j = d; j < a; j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = c; j < b/3; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        c = c + 2;
        d = d - 1;
        System.out.println("");
```

Comment: Basically, the number of rows on the tree, so if they entered 5 it would look like 5 rows of *s progressively getting larger

Comment: Alright, I got it. Does there have to be a top half and a bottom half? Or can it just be 1 pyramid.

Comment: It has to be like a pyramid tree, but then a mini star on top that's like, the top half and bottom half of a pyramid but smaller. Its really weird and I cant quite figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, if you're defining the size as the number of rows.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NestedTree
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the tree you would like");

        int size = scan.nextInt(); // Get the size of the tree

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int spaces = size - i;

            for (int s = 0; s < spaces; s++) { // Print spaces
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (int r = 0; r <= i; r++) { // Print stars
                System.out.print("* ");
            }

            System.out.print("\n"); // new line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow you made it look so easy lol. He wants us to like, put a little star atop the tree that gets larger as the tree itself gets larger. Heres the example he gave us http://imgur.com/lWBJtir